# How can I compare two files in emacs, similar to vim's vimdiff?

Tags: vim, emacs, diff

If I do a diff from emacs, I get something that looks like a patch, and the files are concatenated in one big file. Is there any function that I could use to compare them like in this image? It's much easier to see what's changed.

[image: vimdiff]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ediff works similarly: <kbd>M-x ediff</kbd>

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you ! By the way, maybe you know, is `ediff` written in elisp?

Comment: Yes, see the ediff-*.el files is emacs sources here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp?h=emacs-23

Comment: or just `M-x find-library ediff`

Comment: To get side-by-side diffs: `(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally)`

Comment: It doesn't seem to highlight word differences at all.

Answer (score 9):

Emacs ediff is no way comparable to vimdiff. I think emacs ediff is just a wrapper on Linux diff command. It is just highlighting the lines diff tool marks as changed.

I found vdiff give vimdiff like granularity. Follow instructions at the below link to use it.

https://github.com/justbur/emacs-vdiff